# How to annotate a generator in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

Python 3.x supports (optional) function annotations:

```
def add_ints(x:int, y:int) -> int :
    return x+y
```

I sometimes encounter problems as to how to represent a given "type" can be represented, and this time, I have a function that returns a generator:

```
def myfunc(x: [int]) -> "generator that returns ints":
    #                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    return (n for n in x if n%2 == 0)
```

How should I annotate the return value? Is there any reference I can consult to?

Comment: Specifically what are you trying to accomplish by adding this annotation, Python seems to require nothing save that it be a valid expression, and does not use it internally. There don't seem to be guidelines or standards, so I would just do whatever is easiest for your case.

Comment: @KSab Thank you for the comment. Knowing the absence of guidelines is a good start for me...  Although python does not use annotations internally, invalid expressions are caught, so I can't just `-> generator(int)` without making it a string.

Comment: I suppose you could use types.GeneratorType (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), but you can't specify that it is a generator of `int`s (Python's generators can return multiple types anyway). If you are just doing this for your own type-checking I don't see any reason not to use a string identifier or maybe a global variable.

Comment: `types.GeneratorType` seems to be what I was looking for (Why didn't I search for that!). Thanks for suggesting using string or variables too, I just wasn't certain it can be acceptable at all. Will you spare some more time and post that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) defines the Generator type, which you can use like:

```
Generator[yield_type, send_type, return_type]
```

See also [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: What about cases where generator doesn't have send type or return type? The PEP isn't clear on that.

Comment: @z33k _"If your generator will only yield values, set the SendType and ReturnType to None"_ - from [`Generator` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator)

Comment: Using an Iterator is much simpler, see Conchylicultor's answer

Comment: It seems like you *should* just be able to use Generator[yield_type] if the others can be None.

Comment: Since Python 3.9, [`typing.Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing%20generator#typing.Generator) has been deprecated.  `collections.abc.Generator` should be used now.

Answer (score 83):

While `Generator[x, y, z]` exists, most of the time, you might want to use the less verbose `Iterator`:

```py
def fn(x: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    return (n for n in range(x) if n%2 == 0)
```

Also works for `yield`

```py
def fn(x: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    for n in range(x):
        yield n
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, depend on the minimum.

Comment: Right, 99% of the time, "generator" is an implementation detail, and the public return type is "iterator". Very rarely do you actually want the caller to know you used generators to implement the feature.

Comment: You can go even more abstract and declare the return type to be an `Iterable`, since all iterators should have an `__iter__` method (that returns itself).

Comment: @Blckknght. I think `Iterator` is better as it is more specific. With `Iterable`, calling `next(fn(1))` would fail type checking with: `Iterable` do not have `__next__` method