# How do I declare the type of a python generator

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

What is the correct way of specifying the type of a generator in python?

Say for example I have the generator:

```
def f():
    yield "Banana"
    yield 68
```

How do I specify that it has the type `Union[str,int]`? Is it just `def f() -> Union[str,int]:`?

Comment: This might help: [How to annotate a generator in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264250/how-to-annotate-a-generator-in-python3). It predates the newer style annotations of Python 3.9 but [PEP 593](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0593/) doesn't address generators or iterators so the older technique seems applicable.